# Mixed Models two continuous time-points

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, modeling

I'm using a mixed model to do a hypothesis test of an intervention effect (group: 0=control, 1=intervention) in an RCT with two time-points: Baseline plus follow-up 6 months after baseline. In addition, I want to control for the effect of recruitment-site.

I've got the following questions:

1. I'm studying the following model (lme4 syntax): (y ~ time + group + Baseline_y + time:group + site + (1+time | ID). With: time: 0=baseline, 1=6-month-follow-up; group: 0=control, 1=intervention; baseline_y = baseline value of outcome; site = recruitment-site. Do I need time and the time-slop (if convergence is reached)?
2. As I got other models with more intermediate time points, for which I use weeks as numeric variable, would it be OK to use time as 0 (=baseline) and 26 (= follow-up after 6 months) instead of 0(=baseline) and 1(= follow-up after 6 months)?